# Unknown reason why I'm getting a: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting an undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass when I attempt to save my forum.

Here is my **jobs_controller.rb**:

```
def new
@job_categories = JobCategory.all.map{|c| [ c.title, c.id ] }
@job = Job.new
end


def edit
@job_categories = JobCategory.all.map{|c| [ c.title, c.id ] }
@job = Job.find(params[:id])
end

def create
@job = Job.new(job_params)
respond_to do |format|
if @job.save
    format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @job }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end


def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @job.update(job_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully 
updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @job }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Here is my **jobs/_form.html.erb**:

```
<div class="field-group">
<p>Jobs Category</p>
<%= form.select(:job_category_id, options_for_select(@job_categories)) %>
```

My jobs_categories has it's own controller and model also.
If you need any other information feel free to ask.

[image]

My error is happening when I try to submit my form.

Comment: can you please post back trace for error

Comment: Not related with your error, but you could use `pluck` instead of `map` to get the same result; e.g. `JobCategory.pluck(:title, :id)` (for a solution look at [Bartosz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48589347/6136634)).

Comment: I hope this is what you're looking for ( I posted my error page in my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@job_categories` variable is missing form `create` and `update` actions. It  causes errors when form renders after an unsuccesfull save - `options_for_select` tries to call `.map` on undeclared variable.

Comment: @miklki14567 Did you add the exact same line (i.e. `@job_categories = JobCategory.all.map{|c| [ c.title, c.id ] }`) to `create` action?

Comment: Remember it has to be set before any renders, ideally at beginning of the method. Also check if @job is declared in update action, you have  set it explicitly in all other actions but not in update.

Comment: @Gerry yes that may have fixed my issue. I'm receiving a new error where: 1 error prohibited this job from being saved:
- User must exist... So I need to figure out that big

Comment: @miklki14567 Good, that error is not a bug, its just a validation error: it shows because you must first create a `User` and then assign it to the `Job`.